# date compare week and year format

Tags: mysql, sql

How to the check the dates in condition, when it is in format (ww/yyyy)

example: to check `where Date  > 20.2013`

```
table x:

| Id | DATE  |
--------------
| 1  |21.2013|
| 2  |10.2013|
--------------

result :

-----------
|1 21.2013|
-----------
```

How to check this format ?

Comment: What is the data type od the DATE col?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with `STR_TO_DATE` and the various week formats (they always returned 00/00/year), so how about a brute-force `SUBSTR` to rearrange the year/week:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTR(date, 4), SUBSTR(date, 1, 2)) > 201320
```

If you have the option to do so, I'd recommend storing the week/year as a number in YYYYWW format with no decoration like the dot. You can do comparisons without converting values, and you can isolate the components easily:

```
year: TRUNCATE(date_col / 100, 0)
day: date_col % 100
```